# Pandas grouped mode and missing values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data similar to the table below:

> ```
> Type  Size    Color   Color2
> cat   small   white   white
> cat   small   white   white
> cat   large   brown   #N/A
> cat   large   black   #N/A
> dog   large   white   white
> dog   small   black   black
> cat   small   white   white
> dog   small   brown   brown
> dog   small   brown   brown
> dog   small   brown   brown
> cat   large   brown   #N/A
> cat   large   brown   #N/A
> dog   large   #N/A    brown
> dog   large   white   white
> dog   large   black   black
> cat   large   white   #N/A
> dog   large   brown   brown
> cat   small   white   white
> cat   small   white   white
> dog   large   brown   brown
> dog   large   white   white
> dog   large   #N/A    brown
> dog   small   black   black
> cat   small   white   white
> dog   small   white   white
> dog   small   white   white
> cat   small   white   white
> dog   small   black   black
> dog   small   black   black
> dog   large   brown   brown
> dog   large   brown   brown
> cat   large   black   #N/A
> cat   small   white   white
> ```

The goal is to fill in the missing values in Color and Color2 with the mode of the respective column conditioned on Type and Size.

The below snippet works well for the Color column, and ignores the missing values in the Color column

```
df.groupby(['Type','Size'])['Color'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

However, my actual data resembles what is happening column Color2. In this column all Color2 values corresponding to cat large are missing. As such, when I apply the code snippet below I get an index out of bounds error.

```
df.groupby(['Type','Size'])['Color2'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

I want to be able to return NaN/#N/A, if the specific grouping only has missing values, but return the mode, while ignoring missing values, if there are non-missing values in the grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[0]`, just using `.get(0,'NaN/#N/A')` in your command. It will pick default value `'NaN/#N/A'` if key not found.

```
df['new_color'] = df.groupby(['Type','Size'])['Color2'] \
                    .transform(lambda x: x.mode().get(0,'NaN/#N/A'))

Out[1246]:
   Type   Size  Color Color2 new_color
0   cat  small  white  white     white
1   cat  small  white  white     white
2   cat  large  brown    NaN  NaN/#N/A
3   cat  large  black    NaN  NaN/#N/A
4   dog  large  white  white     brown
5   dog  small  black  black     black
6   cat  small  white  white     white
7   dog  small  brown  brown     black
8   dog  small  brown  brown     black
9   dog  small  brown  brown     black
10  cat  large  brown    NaN  NaN/#N/A
11  cat  large  brown    NaN  NaN/#N/A
12  dog  large    NaN  brown     brown
13  dog  large  white  white     brown
14  dog  large  black  black     brown
15  cat  large  white    NaN  NaN/#N/A
16  dog  large  brown  brown     brown
17  cat  small  white  white     white
18  cat  small  white  white     white
19  dog  large  brown  brown     brown
20  dog  large  white  white     brown
21  dog  large    NaN  brown     brown
22  dog  small  black  black     black
23  cat  small  white  white     white
24  dog  small  white  white     black
25  dog  small  white  white     black
26  cat  small  white  white     white
27  dog  small  black  black     black
28  dog  small  black  black     black
29  dog  large  brown  brown     brown
30  dog  large  brown  brown     brown
31  cat  large  black    NaN  NaN/#N/A
32  cat  small  white  white     white
```

Comment: These looks like it works. Can you, or someone else, explain what's happening and why it works?

Comment: `mode` returns series. `mode()[0]` returns 1st item of the series. On all `NaN` group, `mode` returns empty series, so `mode()[0]` throws errors. Series `.get` provide parameter `default` to return when series is empty. I.e, when key is not found. Therefore, `mode().get(0,'NaN/#N/A')` means get the item `0` from the series returning by `mode`, if not found returns `NaN/#N/A` instead of errors out. Doc of `Series.get`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html#pandas.Series.get

Answer (score 0):

Check with `value_counts`

```
df.fillna(df.groupby(['Type','Size']).transform(lambda x : x.value_counts(dropna=False).index[0]),inplace=True)
```

Or in 0.24 you can pass `dropna=False` in `mode` as well

```
df.groupby(['Type','Size'])['Color2'].transform(lambda x: x.mode(dropna=False)[0])
```